# Software Design Implementation - Issue/Module/Bug/Feature Tracking Solution

Tags: project-management, software-design

The company is growing and we're starting to implement more and more complex software designs. I feel a need for some tracking software... I just don't know if it exists.

I currently maintain a Google Doc Folder (shared by our 3 developers) with a well-organized doc for each module. A doc is also created per major upgrade to a module or modules. For all other "tracking"... we have interal forums.

**I want the following:**
I want get an immediate printout of all Project_01 features or bug fixes on a particular project with the option to hide or show developer comments that have been implemented in the last X number of days.

This clearly suggests a web-based system where developers enter issues, bugs, and features with appropriate tagging. Entries should be commentable, taggable, dated, editable and reporting should be based upon tags, dates, developers, projects, etc.

I figure I'm going to be perceived as naive by the grizzled veterans floating around here, though I've been running this business for 4 years (so I've been around). I don't think we have the resources to absorb the overhead of implementing something like CMMI... but then again, I don't really know what's best.

My personal evolution to using Google Docs per Application Module + internal phpbb forums for everything else has been pretty nice compared to the way we started out (marker boards, Microsoft Word docs). I just feel like I can go a long ways towards exceeding client expectations if I had the ability to track features/bugs/issues better with superior on-demand reporting.

Thoughts?

Update: Went with MediaWiki integrated with Mantis

Comment: Thanks to everybody for their input. I did not realize that bug-tracking solutions also server as issue + inquiry + software design implementation solutions. After playing around with a few, I can say that I am very happy with the suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [fogbugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/).  It looks like it meets all your requirements.

Also, take a look at this other SO question:  [Free/Cheap Task/Bug Management software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86394/free-cheap-task-bug-management-software/86722#86722)

Comment: I agree, it does meet all of my requirements. I'm giving it a try. It'll obviously increase my business overhead expenses... we'll see how it competes with Mantis + (plugins to make it less of an eye sore)

Answer (score 3):

I've good experiences with mantis.   http://www.mantisbt.org

Comment: I regurlarly use mantis. Easy to install/use. A good balance between functionnality and simplicity.

Comment: ANd well, it can be easily coupled with sunversion ...

Comment: I like the idea that there are plugins and I can modify it to meet my needs. FogBugz is great to use so far, but... costs money per developer and I have to pay for every single upgrade. Either way, I'm going to give them both an honest chance.

Comment: What's the deal with the interface being horribly ugly and hard to look at? I mean, FogBugz isn't "pretty", but at least my eyes don't hurt after using it for 10 minutes. I'm going to spend a few hours on it regardless.. hopefully I can find some plugins to make it more aesthetic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) and [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) are recommended.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Well, I'd say FogBugz looks pretty nice. It meets every single one of my requirements. I'm going to spend several hours with it because I think this will go a long ways towards increasing our productivity and becoming more and more responsive to clients. I'm also looking at Mantis

Answer (score 0):

I find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems) comparison of issue tracking systems either interesting or overwhelming.

I think with 3 developers, in the same building, you probably can get by without software tools. But, adopting something now, before you're so big/complex that you can't survive without it may save a lot of future pain.

Comment: I disagree with "I think with 3 developers, in the same building, you probably can get by without software tools".  I think I'd get a bug tracking system even if it was just one developer.  The key is exposure to clients.  If open source software projects can have respectable bug tracking software, I see no reason why this company shouldn't.  It creates a perception of seriousness, IMO.

Comment: I'm in agreement. We've "gotten by" for a while. I'd like to be a bit more responsive with respect to status updates and fix reports for clients.